# how to create a list which contains another list in C

Tags: c

so i wanted to create a sub list liste_fav of the main list abbones , and here is the structure

```
  /*********************************/
typedef struct liste_fav
{
       signed char numf[20];
       struct liste_fav *suiv;

}liste_fav;

/***********************************/

typedef struct abonnes// lz structure principale
{
    signed char  num_c[20];
    signed  char operateur [20];
    signed char profil[20];
    int credit;
    liste_fav *liste;// on sait pas si on doit mettre une etoile ici
    struct abonnes *adr;
}abonnes;
```

si I have created a list that contains
i want to create the main list that contains the information about the subscriber and his information we have a pointer to another sub list that contains the favourite numbers of this subscriber .
I want to create an application that will allow the subscriber to manipulate his list of favourite numbers ( adding a new one , or deleting ...) , before this I have to record data in the main and the sub list . I've done this function that allow us fill up the information and also to full the list of favourite numbers ,  ,could you help please
P.S:I have a doubt that is : the affectation of the head of the sub list in the field (liste_fav *liste)

the functions used :

```
liste_fav *allouer_fav ()// allouer un espace memoire, elle retourne l'adresse de l'espace alloue
{
    return ((liste_fav*)malloc(sizeof(liste_fav)));
}


abonnes *allouer_abo () 
{
    return ((abonnes*)malloc(sizeof(abonnes)));
}

void creation_abo(abonnes **R)
    {
        signed char ope [20],numm[20],prof[20],rr[20],num[20];
        abonnes *s,*tet;
        liste_fav *b,*a;
        //(*R)->liste=NULL;
        int i,cred,no,eee;
        int k=1;
        printf(" number of nodes to create : ");
        scanf("%d",&no);//the number of the nodes to link of the list abonnes
        printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
        *R= allouer_abo();
        printf("operateur  %d :",k);
        scanf("%s",&ope);
        aff_operateur(R,ope);//strcpy((p -> operateur ),r);
        printf("his number:");
        scanf("%s",&numm);
        aff_num_c(R,numm);//strcpy((p -> num_c),num)
        printf("donnez son credit : ");
        scanf("%d",&cred);
        aff_credit(R,cred);// p-> credit =n;
        printf("donnez son profil : ");
        scanf("%s",&prof);
        aff_profil(R,prof);//strcpy((p->profil),f)
        printf("creation de la liste des favoris: ");
        printf("donnez le nombre de mailons a creer :");
        scanf("%d",&eee);
        printf("donnez le numero du contact 1 : ");
        scanf("%s",&rr);
       // abonnes *pp = (*R )->liste -> numf;

         //strcpy(pp,rr);
         abonnes *J= (*R)->liste ;//I have doubt here, it's supposed to be the affectation oh the head of the list in J
         J=allouer_fav();//return ((liste_fav*)malloc(sizeof(liste_fav)));
         affnum_fav_propre(J,rr);//strcpy((p ->numf ),n);

         for ( i=1;i<eee;i++)
         {

        b=allouer_fav();
        printf("donnez le numero du contact %d :",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&num);
        affnum_fav_propre(b,num);strcpy((p ->numf ),n);
        aff_adr_fav_propre(J,b);// s -> suiv = q; s a pointer to list abonnes


    }
    aff_adr_fav_propre(b,NULL);


// we affected the heads, now we will affect the other structures to link
        tet= R;
        for(i=1;i<no;i++)
        {
            k++;
            s= allouer_abo();
            printf("_-__-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_\n");


                printf("give the operateur %d :",k);
             scanf("%s",&ope);
            aff_operateur(s,ope);
            printf("donnez son numero : ");
            scanf("%s",&numm);
            aff_num_c(s,numm);
            printf("the credit : ");
            scanf("%d",&cred);
             aff_credit(s,cred);
            printf("the  profil : ");
           scanf("%s",&prof);
           aff_profil(s,prof);
            printf("creation  of list favoris: ");
        printf(" numbre of nodes you wanna create :");
        scanf("%d",&eee);
        printf(" numero the favoris 1 : ");
        scanf("%s",&rr);
        abonnes *J= (*R)->liste ;
         J=allouer_fav();
         affnum_fav_propre(J,rr);


         for ( i=1;i<eee;i++)
         {

        b=allouer_fav();
        printf("numero  %d :",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&num);
        affnum_fav_propre(b,num);// strcpy((p ->numf ),n);
        aff_adr_fav_propre(J,b);// s -> suiv = q;
        J=b;


    }
   // aff_adr_fav_propre(b,NULL);
             aff_adr_abo(R,s);//p-> adr=q
             R=s;

        }
        aff_adr_abo(R,NULL);
        aff_adr_fav_propre(b,NULL);

        //s=NULL;
        ////tet=NULL; i was not sure
        return ( tet);

    }
```

Any help or proposition? hope you understood my problem

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a good problem description. Please review: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your doubt is correct. This line:

```
abonnes *J= (*R)->liste;
```

will not give you the desired result. Also, J needs to be a `liste_fav*`, not an `abonnes*`. Like so:

```
liste_fav* J = allouer_fav();
(*R)->liste = J;
```

You'll need to make the same change in the code below.

[As an aside, you'd make your life easier if you created a function which populated a single `abonnes` instance, and call it once for the head, then inside the "affect other structures to link" loop. As it is, you've got a large chunk of duplicated code which you'll have to fix twice.]

I have my doubt about `aff_adr_fav_propre` because you don't show the code, and the comment is wrong [it is not "a pointer to list abonnes", it is "a pointer to liste_fav"]. It needs to perform the following:

```
J->suiv = b;
J = b;
```

Also you fail to mention in your writeup is the problems you have with returning the results. You attempt to return `tet`, but you've declared `creation_abo` to be void. I think what you want to do is declare it as follows:

```
abonnes *creation_abo()
{
<existing code>
    return tet;
}
```

The caller would look like this:

```
abonnes *master_list = creation_abo();
```

Your life would be improved with consistent indentation and descriptive variable names as well.